# What are the pros and cons of these two coding patterns/structures? And do they have a formal term?

Tags: programming-languages, design-patterns

I have traditionally been doing things like this:

```
function test() // A
{
    if (/* conditions */)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Of late, I have instead starting doing, and converting existing code like the example above, into this:

```
function test() // B
{
    if (/* conditions */)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

I can see arguments for both ways, but the "new" way (to me) seems to win after all. I used to not "parse" code correctly in my head, so I thought that it could sometimes continue executing the code in a function after a "return" has been encountered, which is not actually the case in reality. At least I think (and hope) so...

I'm interested in hearing objective arguments for/against what we can call "A" or "B" for simplicity.

Comment: Look at the “guard” statement in Swift and think when you would use it.

Comment: (Then again, the *condition* **is** a boolean - just `return condition;`)